# sum of relatively prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=\gcd(a,c)=1$. Then, $\{an+b:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap\{cn+d:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\neq\emptyset$. Why is that? I think I missed something silly...

Comment: Apply the linked CRT solvability Theorem to the system $\, x \equiv b\pmod{a},\ x\equiv d\pmod{c}\ \ $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume $a> 0$ and $c> 0$. Since $\gcd(a,c) = 1$, a multiple of Bézout's identity is

$$ax - cy = d-b$$

for some $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.

To obtain positive $x',y'$ based on $x,y$, note that

$$\begin{align*}
ac - ca &= 0\\
a(x+kc) - c(y+ka) &= d-b\\
a(x+kc) + b &= c(y+ka)+d
\end{align*}$$

So regardless of whether $x,y\in\mathbb N$, for sufficiently large $k$, both $x'=x+kc \in \mathbb N$ and $y'=y+ka \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Please don't answer dupes of FAQs.